# Getting an ISO from host to guest on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I am running VirtualBox on my Mac and have a Windows Server 2008 as the guest OS.

I need to get a SQL Server ISO from my host to the guest so I can install it on my Windows server. How can I do so?

Comment: have you tried sharing folders?

Answer (score 4):

Just set the ISO as a virtual CD/DVD image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can share folders [here](http://scoobygalletas.blogspot.mx/2011/06/how-to-share-files-with-virtualbox.html) is one tutorial.

You can also put the ISO on a USB and then capture the USB with the virtual box and use it in Windows virtual machine